# Move site collection to production making dev. Content DB as Production DB

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, site-collection, publishing-site, production

We have a SharePoint 2013 farm, development environment where one site collection alone is residing in a separate DB server.

Now we plan to move this site collection to production with the existing database server as production database server.

We are not planning to keep Dev environment for this site collection now .(this will be taken care later).

Can someone suggest the best suitable approach?

P.S : Publishing feature is enabled for this site collection.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend backing up the DB in DEV and restore it to your Production SQL server, then mount the DB to the webapp.  Changing from one SQL server to another is more difficult because all your service application DBs etc. are already on your current Production SQL server.

Comment: There is no separate DEV and Prod SQL server.I just needed to make this sql server as prod sql server . So  I think just mounting this database to production web application would be suffice ?